# How to use a function to create a matrix and then access elements of the matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to do Coursera's Andrew Ng class on Machine Learning. I'm struggling right now to figure out how to get my function to work. I keep getting an error that some element isn't defined. If it helps, I am on the "Advanced Optimization" video

```
import numpy as np

def sampleFunc(x, y): 
    x = ((T1 - 5)^2 + (T2 - 5)^2) 

    y = np.zeros((2, 1)) 
    y[0][0] = 2(T1 - 5) 
    y[1][0] = 2(T2 - 5) 

print(sampleFunc(x,y))
```

The errors I get is either T1 or T2 is not defined or that sampleFunc requires 2 inputs and I'm giving none

Comment: What are `T1,T2,x,y` have you assigned anything to them? When you call the function with `print(sampleFunc(x,y))` nothing has been assigned to those variables.

Comment: I'm operating under the premise that these are two variables that the program has to find using gradient descent

Comment: Not enough context in the question - unless something has been assigned to those variables (within the function's outer scope) you will get that error.